# Yosemite hdiutil: create failed - error -5341

Tags: macos

I could successfully use hdiutil for creating a dmg file for my program in Mountain Lion, but after upgrading to Yosemite (and after updating it to 10.10.1), when I execute

```
hdiutil create -srcfolder build/Thonny.app Thonny-0.2.5.dmg
```

I get following error:

```
hdiutil: create failed - error -5341
```

Verbose mode didn't reveal anything useful.

Folder build/Thonny.app contains a Python application.

Any idea what this error means and what to try next?

UPDATE: Looks like the number of files in my app affects the result. When I remove one of the files (doesn't matter which one), then the command is able to produce the result. Currently there are about 70 files and few folders under Thonny.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: What's the command you type ?

Comment: Try to set a filesize

Comment: @Thomas, no luck, "hdiutil create -size 200k -srcfolder build/Thonny.app Thonny-0.2.5.dmg" gives me "hdiutil: create failed - Operation not permitted"

Comment: And with a sudo ?

Comment: Same result with sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a workaround. If I do

```
hdiutil create -srcfolder build Thonny-0.2.5.dmg
```

instead of

```
hdiutil create -srcfolder build/Thonny.app Thonny-0.2.5.dmg
```

(ie provide the parent of the app folder instead of app folder itself), then it works.

Comment: Another thread I found and what could be useful for people having similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621467/error-creating-disk-image-using-hdutil

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error -5341 and was able to work around it with the -megabytes option as suggested [here](https://github.com/autopkg/autopkg/issues/87).

```
hdiutil create -megabytes 130 Reassembly.dmg -srcfolder Reassembly
```

In this case the Reassembly directory is 107M and the resulting Reassembly.dmg is 97M. The `-size 130m` option did not work for me. My issue was intermittent - adding or removing one or two files would fix it or break it.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but had to use `-megabytes 900` instead of `-megabytes 130`. Note that I didn't try any intermediate values, but just wanted to choose a number that I was hoping was "large enough". With a value of 130, I got the message `hdiutil: create failed - No space left on device`